# Separate email address from given string format

Tags: php, regex

I have the following type of data in txt format and there are hundreds of lines as below.
How to only fetch emails from them.

```
email1@yahoo.com,US,Wolterman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=12
email2@yahoo.com,UK,superman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=21
```

Comment: That line format is called "CSV".

Comment: a simple `^[^,]+` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this if the addresses are always first.

```
$text = <<<DATA
email1@yahoo.com,US,Wolterman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=12
email2@yahoo.com,UK,superman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=21
email3@yahoo.com,US,Wolterman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=12
email4@yahoo.com,UK,superman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=21
email5@yahoo.com,US,Wolterman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=12
email6@yahoo.com,UK,superman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=21
DATA;

preg_match_all('~^[^,]+~m', $text, $matches);
echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
```

Output

```
email1@yahoo.com
email2@yahoo.com
email3@yahoo.com
email4@yahoo.com
email5@yahoo.com
email6@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file is in text file and, each is in one line then you could extract each line and get email....

```
$array = array(); // Array where emails are stored

$handle = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");  
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $array[] = explode(",",$line)[0]; // stores email in the array

    }
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
fclose($handle);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Why not `fgetcsv()` instead of rolling your own?

Comment: yeah..that can be used... :P

Comment: Sometimes, it just takes knowing something is there for you already! :)

Answer (score 1):

try `explode()`

```
$str = 'email1@yahoo.com,US,Wolterman,http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=12';
$res = explode(',', $str);
echo $res[0]; //email1@yahoo.com
```

Comment: ok but i have hundreds of lines cannot pass one by one ,
how can i pass them to $str and run a loop?

Comment: getting result from db? then use explode in your loop

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below regex

```
/.*?@.*?(?=,)/g
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/pH5nC5/2)

Or another option would be to split the text on `\n` and then iterating on each line, split on `,` and capture the first element. This however is a bit over kill, when you can match it wasily with the above regex.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be nice sometimes to use native implementations of things, like [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv):

```
<?php
$emails = [];
if (($handle = fopen("emails.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $emails[] = array_shift($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```